# Confirmation Email sent through smtp client is not sending the complete url c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I'm building a confirmation email process after a user registers in my ASP.NET App.
Here's my code:

```
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = new Uri(Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }));

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 25);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(credentials, credentials);
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.Body = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\""
                                                + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>";

            mail.From = new MailAddress(Address, App);
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(user.Email));
            //mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));

            smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Here's the confirm email:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ConfirmEmail", Name = "ConfirmEmailRoute")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId = "", string code = "")
    {
        //var _result = XElement.Parse(success).Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Id and Code are required");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var response = new JObject();
            response.Add(new JProperty("Email Verified", "You can now log in to the app."));
            return Ok(response);
        }
        else
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }
    }
```

This email is being sent successfully on desktop app and on Gmail app on mobile phone.
For apple devices, the mail app doesn't take the link fully
I.E.

> callbackurl is not all included in the Link

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add :

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

the link was sent was fully.